# Material Design Icon font Issue with circle outline

Tags: html, css, material-design

When I try to use the material design icon font , I am facing issue when i use the icon with outline like(see the code below), Circle outline is not coming

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons"
      rel="stylesheet">

<i class="material-icons">remove circle outline</i>
<i class="material-icons">add circle outline</i>
<i class="material-icons">pause circle outline</i>
```

see this codepen http://codepen.io/shmdhussain/pen/BKXjjN.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use underscore for the class name.

Instead of:

`<i class="material-icons">remove circle outline</i>`

use:

`<i class="material-icons">remove_circle_outline</i>`